# Run NodeJs on port 80

Tags: node.js, linux, port

I am trying to host my app on port 80. I know that it is a root port. I tried running my app with sudo, but no luck. P.S I am using Linux 16.04 LTS server. Thx!

Comment: You probably will have some other server running on port 80.

Comment: `No luck`, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Does your node app NEED to run on port 80?  I would recommend using Apache or Nginx and then reverse proxy to your app.

Comment: @Aldose - You don't need a proxy for that.  You can just use an iptable config to forward port 80 to a higher port you are running on.

Comment: Iptables doesn't work. I get do you need to install insmod?